# The record is not deleting or status is not update in cron job after email send in loop

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-queue

And also please check the code below Laravel Cron Job the compiler is not go to the if condition after sending mail. Its not deleting or update the status when email fails. Please see the code. What should I do for that. After sending mail, if mail fails means i.e Mail::fails function its not to do any think. I want to change the status if mails fails and delete the record if mail send successfully. Please help me

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use App\Mail\SendEmail;
use App\Models\CronjobSetting;
use App\Models\ProcessingEmail;
use App\Models\SmtpServer;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class SendEmailsBasedonDate extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $signature = 'sendemailviadate:cron';

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Command description';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
        public function handle()
        {
            $cronJob = CronjobSetting::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())->first();
            if ($cronJob->email_group_type == 1) {
                $processingEmails = ProcessingEmail::all();
                foreach ($processingEmails as $processingEmail) {
                    $smtpServer = SmtpServer::where('id', $processingEmail->smtp_id)->first();
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $smtpServer->hostname);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $smtpServer->port);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $smtpServer->username);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $smtpServer->password);
    
                    $email = new SendEmail($processingEmail);
                    Mail::to($processingEmail->recipient_email)->send($email);
                    if (Mail::failures()) {
                        ProcessingEmail::where('id', $processingEmail->id)->update(
                            ['status' => 3]
                        );
                    } else {
                        ProcessingEmail::destroy($processingEmail->id);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $processingEmails = ProcessingEmail::where('email_group_id', $cronJob->email_group_id)->get();
                foreach ($processingEmails as $processingEmail) {
                    $smtpServer = SmtpServer::where('id', $processingEmail->smtp_id)->first();
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.host', $smtpServer->hostname);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.port', $smtpServer->port);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.username', $smtpServer->username);
                    Config::set('mail.mailers.smtp.password', $smtpServer->password);
    
                    $email = new SendEmail($processingEmail);
                    Mail::to($processingEmail->recipient_email)->send($email);
                    if (Mail::failures()) {
                        ProcessingEmail::where('email_leads_id', $processingEmail->email_lead_id)->update(
                            ['status' => 3]
                        );
                    } else {
                        ProcessingEmail::where('email_leads_id', $processingEmail->email_lead_id)->delete();
                    }
                }
    
                return Command::SUCCESS;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're calling destroy instead of just doing `$processingEmail->delete()`

Comment: i also tried delete instead of destroy its also did not work. i think compiler is not come to this point

Comment: I would suggest some logging to figure out where it's going. My favorite method with laravel is `Log::info(__FILE__.':'.__LINE__);` at certain points, which then gets logged to a file in `storage/logs`.  You can add other information inside of the function to provide more information.